# X11 XGetImage BadMatch Error (invalid parameter attributes)

Tags: c++, opencv, x11

I am trying to capture a screenshot on my linux pc. The compilation of code is fine but if I try to execute it, it keeps throwing same error as below:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  73 (X_GetImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  7
  Current serial number in output stream:  7
```

Can anybody help me to figure out what is the problem?

Here's the code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Display* d = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    auto root = DefaultRootWindow(d);

    auto img = XGetImage(d, root, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
    auto rimg = Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC4, img->data);
    imshow("test image", rimg);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your DISPLAY environment variable set?  If it is, try using NULL instead of nullptr

Comment: I didn't touch any other thing. And the NULL doesn't work.

Comment: If the parameter of XOpenDisplay is NULL or nullptr, it takes the value of the DISPLAY environment variable.  If your DISPLAY environment variable is not set, then it will give you errors.

Comment: I've echoed my $DISPLAY environment variable, and it showed `:0`. Is it the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetImage.html

*BadMatch   An InputOnly window is used as a Drawable.*

*BadMatch   Some argument or pair of arguments has the correct type and range but fails to match in some other way required by the request.*

You need to map the window first before getting an image of it.  Use

```
XMapRaised(d, root);
```

before calling XGetImage

Comment: still doesn't work. This is the error what I got: `X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  73 (X_GetImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  9
  Current serial number in output stream:  9
`

Comment: What size is your display - is it at least 1000x1000 or smaller?  You will get this error if the display is smaller than 1000x1000.

Comment: If it is smaller than 1000x1000 change the width and height parameters of XGetImage to the size of your screen

Comment: My screen resolution is a standard Full HD screen. And I did try a smaller width and height like 100 * 100 and it didn't work as well. I also tried to let my friend to run this simple code. What surprised me is that he got the same error as mine.

Comment: I'm running on a 1024x768 screen - setting the width and height to 1024, 768 seems to work OK.  I don't really know what the limits on size are.

Comment: After I reinstall os, your code does work on my computer. Thx a lol!